# Nodejs function evaluation explanation

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express

I have just started using Nodejs and Expressjs to build custom application. I am having some troubles in understanding a piece of code. I am not sure why this code works. Would appreciate if I get an explanation on the code or a better method to do the same.

**Ingredients used**

I am using Nodejs V0.10.25 and Express V3.4.8

**The Scenario**

The piece of code is for login authentication. The usernames and passwords are in JSON format. A JS function takes in the username and password submitted from a form in POST as arguments, checks against the JSON. If the username and password matches in the JSON then the function returns true else it returns false.

Below are the codes

**JSON file**

```
[{
    "username": "abc@example.com",
    "password": "abc",
    "name": "ABC"
}, {
    "username": "def@example.com",
    "password": "def",
    "name": "DEF"
}, {
    "username": "xyz@example.com",
    "password": "xyz",
    "name": "XYZ"
}]
```

**JSON verify function in app.js**

```
/* Verify login from JSON */
function verifyLogin(username, password) {
    var file = 'json/login.json';

    fs.readFile(file, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
      }

      data = JSON.parse(data);

      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if(data[i].username === username && data[i].password === password) {
              return true;
          } else {
              return false;
          }
      }

    });
}
```

**Function to check if the user is already logged in in app.js**

```
/* Check if session exists and user is logged in */
function checkAuth(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.user_id) {
    res.send('You are not authorized to view this page');
  } else {
    next();
  }
}
```

**app.post() to get the POST values and redirect appropriately in app.js**

```
/* Login: Check POST email and password and redirect user */
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  var post = req.body;
  if(post.email && post.password){
      if (verifyLogin) {
          /* Why is verifyLogin() working WITHOUT parameters */
          req.session.user_id = post.email;
          res.redirect('/inside');
      }
  } else {
      res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Logged in',
        error: 'The username and password you entered is incorrect'
    });
  }
});
```

**Now the question**

Why is the verifyLogin() is being evaluated in the if() block within app.post WITHOUT passing the username and password from POST as parameters?

I am sure, I am doing something wrong out here. It would really be great if any one can help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`verifyLogin` is a `Function` object. All objects evaluate to true.

That is, when a non-boolean type is used in a conditional context, it is converted to a `Boolean` object. In ECMA-speak, it will be converted using the abstract `ToBoolean` operation.

```
Boolean(verifyLogin) //true

!!verifyLogin //true
```

Also, you're reading the login.json file every time user authentication is required. Read it at start-up and cache the login object. You also don't need to use `fs.readFile` since a .json file can be exported using `require`

```
var login = require('json/login.json');
```

A better way would be to use `verifyLogin` as a middleware:
`Array.prototype.any` will suit well for this by returning as soon as the condition evaluates to true

```
function verifyLogin() {
  var login = require('json/login');
  return function (req, res, next) {
    var body = req.body,
    authenticated = login.any(function (user) {
      return body.email === user.username && body.password === user.password;
    });
    if(authenticated) {
      req.session.user_id = body.email;
      res.redirect('/inside');
    }
    else {
      res.render('index', { 
    title: 'Logged in',
    error: 'The username and password you entered is incorrect'
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for your quick response. So, is this the correct way to go about or is there a more better way?

Comment: Invoking `verifyLogin` with username and password is the correct way. You can simplify it by using `verifyLogin` as a middleware

Comment: Cool. Thanks for all the help. Will convert this as a middleware and check.

Answer (score 1):

```
function verifyLogin(username, password) {
    var file = 'json/login.json';
    var isValidUser = false;
    try {
        var data = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if(data[i].username === username && data[i].password === password) {
              isValidUser = true;
          }
        }
        return isValidUser;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return false;
    }
}
```

The code in this callback will not return anything but true. because this is a async callback. check the syncReadFile function!

Comment: Valuable info. I think, I can use this. Thanks!
Also, I think you meant to check the readFileSync() [http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_filename_options] correct?